# How to implement drop-down menus like below?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

http://losangeles.kijiji.com/c-SelectCategory

That page's search menus on upper left.

Best with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this. You can use plain 'ol [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets).

[This article](http://pixelspread.com/blog/289/css-drop-down-menu) from pixelspread shows how to create a CSS Drop Down Menu [resulting in this](http://pixelspread.com/demo/cssdropdown.html). You might also want to look into these following:

1. [CSS Horizontal Drop-Down-Menu](http://sperling.com/examples/menuh/)
2. [Simple JavaScript Drop Down Menu ( If you really want a JavaScript based one. )](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/simple_drop_down_menu/)
3. [jQuery Drop Down Menu ( Written with jQuery if you like that.. )](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu/)
4. [Another one in jQuery + CSS with very good examples and help around it.](http://css-tricks.com/simple-jquery-dropdowns/)
5. [You could also check out this page, which provides you with code for a jQuery Drop Down Menu ( provided in the other posters link )](http://www.bunchacode.com/programming/shadow-menu/)

Answer (score 0):

For a really simple & lightweight solution, check the [Son of Suckerfish dropdowns](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/). Silly name but very elegant. It uses the `:hover` pseudo-class to accomplish its magic.